# Looking for JS datepicker modular script that can plug in to custom JS date range picker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar

(This might not be specific enough for StackOverflow, but I do have actual code samples. If you think it's too vague, let me know in a comment or vote to close.)

#### Background

I'm designing a date range picker for an internal web application. The way it works is that clicking on an input will pop up a list of pre-defined ranges, similar to how date range selection works on Google results:

[image]

Only if a user taps on Custom Range/Date will they get a calendar. There are panels inside the popup, sliding sideways, and they'll see one or two calendars (if range or if single date).

#### Problem

I'm looking for a date picker script that I can plug into my existing custom date picker class. I'd like to be able to call it from JS, and attach a callback to return the date. There will be no `input` HTML elements.

A perfect API in my mind would let me do something like this:

```
var beginDatePicker = new DatePicker({
    default: beginDate,
    callback: function(event){
        // do stuff with returned date
    }
})
... .appendChild( beginDatePicker.el.wrapper );
```

That way I could create a calendar, then use the callback to store the date and animate to second calendar, and then finally place the dates in the hidden inputs.

I can't find any open-source datepicker scripts that are modular though. They all require an `input` element, but I need to be able to create and destroy the calendars as I go.

Do anyone know of a library/script/class that works in the above manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

It doesn't exist, anywhere I can find. The solution is just to take an open source option, fork it, strip out the pieces that I need, and use that.